# Unable to select the specified database: conection to localhost (PHP with MySQL) in windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been trying to connect to my database so I can make some changes in a website, in a local way, not directly on the server. But I always come to this error:

> "Unable to select the specified database: backup"

. It says that the problem is in the file:

**Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php**

**Line Number: 141.**

But this is what I have in the line:

```
$this->display_error('db_unable_to_select', $this->database);
```

My script is like this:

```
$db['default']['username'] = 'teste';
$db['default']['password'] = '123456';
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['database'] = 'backup';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = 'tbl_';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I changed the name of the driver, but it didn't work as well.

the line of code that try to select the db:

```
function db_select()
{
    return @mysqli_select_db($this->database, $this->conn_id);
}
```

How to proceed?

Comment: a) **where** is the code that does the actual work? b) does the database `teste` actually exist?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes, the database exist, and I don't know what do you mean by your first question....

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I'm trying to use the database **backup**, the databse teste exist and it is the same as the database **backup**

Comment: any error related to *selecting a database* **must** originate from a piece of code where you actually *select a database*. in your question, there **is no such code**, only some configuration parameters and an error output.

Comment: sorry, i read to quickly. the question should be: does the database `backup` **definitely** exist? also: is your user privileged to *access* said database?

Comment: **don't** post code as comments. **edit** your question instead, take care of proper **formatting** and include maybe more than just one line?

Comment: The database exist and I have grant all privileges to my user.....